# Windows 10, Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to make column headers longer, not wider - I have short data and long column headings. Excel only gives one row, I need 4 so they are not included in the sorting feature.

Comment: Excel allows you to have more than one row as header (Page Layout, Sheet). Set up your header rows and exclude them from Sort.

Comment: You need `Merge Cel`l or possibly `Wrap Text & Merge Cell` both, Check `Cell Format` command TAG from `HOME`.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose two ways：

1.Extend the cell of this headers, but the following data will also be longer:

[image]

2.As Rajesh says, you can merge cells (which is probably the best way for you):

[image]